# retrieving rows based on another rows laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working over a basic system where blogs retrieve the image from other database table but it shows the posts not the photos
here is my controller:

```
$bloginfo=bloginfo::where('blog_name','=',$name)->first();
    $blogposts=pageposts::where('p_id','=',$bloginfo->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    foreach($blogposts as $posts){
        $photoscount=pagephotos::where('b_id','=',$posts->id)->count();
        $blogphotos=pagephotos::where('b_id','=',$posts->id)->get();

    }
    return View::make('myblog')
    ->with('bloginfo',$bloginfo)
    ->with('blogposts',$blogposts)
    ->with('blogphotos',$blogphotos)
    ->with('photoscount',$photoscount);
```

and here is my view:

```
@foreach($blogposts as $posts)
                    <div class="panel panel-default">    
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @if($photoscount==0)
                                {{ null }}
                            @elseif($photoscount==1)
                           //a bunch of code here
                              @else

                               //a bunch of code here
                              @endif
                            <h4><a href="">{{ $posts->title }}</a></h4>
                            <p>{{ $posts->description }}</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: Are you getting photos in your controller? Have you checked using print_r ?

Comment: I am only retriving the phots name based on the post. Means when i post title description and more than one images in a post so thr title and drscription will be inserted in a table than the photos names will be posted in the other table with the same blog id(b_id) now i want to retrive images with the blogs.

Comment: Are you getting image url ? or image name? if image name then are these images saved on the same server. Or you got some path to access them.

Comment: I want to get the image name and by the way thank you i found my answer. I should get the results in the view not at controller thabk you

Answer (score 1):

Might i suggest you looking into to relationships, this could also be your answer.

You can eager load all the data within one query.

```
bloginfo::with('posts', 'posts.images')->where('blog_name','=',$name)->first();
```

This will load the blog posts with all the information that relates to it, i.e. the posts, and their images. Look here for setting them up. [HERE](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

As your current problem is within your for loop you overwrite the variables you are setting n times, i.e. by the amount of posts there are. So potentially you will always have different results.